# How to detect BLE beacons on Unity3D HoloLens app?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, hololens

I have built an app in Unity3D which should be able to detect Bluetooth Low-Energy beacons on the Microsoft HoloLens. Here is the Unity C# script code that I used to get this done.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement;

public class BeaconDetector : MonoBehaviour
{

    private BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher _watcher;

    void Start()
    {
        _watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
        _watcher.Received += WatcherOnReceived;
        _watcher.Start();
    }

    //This method should be called when a beacon is detected
    void WatcherOnReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        //Just a simple check if this method is even called
        Debug.Log("Beacon detected!");
    }

}
```

The app builds and runs on the HoloLens nicely, but (even after waiting a couple of minutes) I do not get the desired output line in my debug log. This means to me that the `WatcherOnReceived()` method is never called, which ultimately **means that no beacon is detected**.

I use some **Sensoro SmartBeacon-4AA**'s which can transmit both iBeacon and Eddystone signals.

I have been trying this for a couple of weeks right now, did several tutorials along the way but I still can not figure out why this is not working for me.

Comment: Did you already try running [this sample app](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/6947/hololens-and-beacons) (2nd post by Matt Fedorovich)?

Comment: Yes, it is basicly the same tutorial as the one I mentioned but it is written down slightly different

Comment: So that app works like expected or isn't working either? Because if it doesn't maybe you have a hardware failure or a permission problem?

Comment: Hey this is Matt, the writer of the DLL you should be using.  Using the native Windows Devices lib will not work inside Unity for the version of Unity you need to build this with.  You should/could be using my HoloBeaconScanner DLL and use the Scanner class.  I built all the detecting and parsing in there for you.  Just follow the steps in either blog post and you should be good to go.  Again, no need to reference the Windows Devices libs, I already did it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a permission problem after all. It is possible to solve this issue in both Unity (pre-build) and Visual Studio (post-build). Here are both solutions:

#### Solution A: in Unity

1. Head to **Edit > Project Settings > Player**.
2. In the **Inspector**, open up the tab **Publishing Settings**.
3. Under the **Capabilities** section, make sure that **Bluetooth is enabled**.

[image]
*Click on the .gif to expand*

#### Solution B: in Visual Studio (2017)

1. In your **Solution Explorer** (Ctrl+Alt+L), expand your project.
2. Double-click the **Package.appxmanifest**.
3. Go to the **Capabilities** tab.
4. Again, make sure that **Bluetooth is enabled**.

[image]
*Click on the .gif to expand*

This will give your app the right to use Bluetooth on the HoloLens.